# Проблема со слиянием веток

Tags: git, gitlab

Коллеги, есть вопрос. Есть 2 ветки :
Мастер и ХотФикс.
В Мастере должны быть только стабильные изменения.
В ХотФиксе заплатки и прочие.
Дело в следующем: надо слить ветки, только выборочно А именно есть из-за истории коммитов образовалось 2 файла. Один нормальный, второй проблемный. Как мне при слиянии веток. А именно новые изменения из ХотФикса перекинуть в Мастер но чтобы изменился только один файл. Причём тот, который Я хочу. А второй проблемный даже не подгружался бы.

Comment: Ничего непонятно, но есть смутное ощущение что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то не то и не понимаете как и зачем вообще используется контроль версий.

Comment: из заголовка непонятно, из меток тоже - гитлаб или гитхаб? Поправь заголовкок и убери ненужную метку. И судя по всему, вопрос вообще неспецифичен ни для одного из сервисов, так что можно убирать обе метки и упоминание сервиса в заголовке

Comment: Сейчас исправим)

Comment: Для этого существует `cherry-pick`. Посмотрите как правильно пользоваться этой командой. И оно вам поможет) Переключаетесь на master и пишите `git cherry-pick <ветка где нужный коммит> <хэш комита который нужен>` Примерно так: `git cherry-pick hot-fix af42d`

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понял, что куда, но думаю Вам это поможет. Ниже написал Вам алгоритм как соединить 2 ветки, например на `master` - стабильный проект, а на `developer_test` - велась разработка, которая уже оттестена и надо залить на `master`:

1)ПЕРЕКЛЮЧИТЬСЯ НА ОСНОВНУЮ ВЕТКУ "master"

```
git checkout master
```

2)ВЫПОЛНИТЬ СЛИЯНИЕ С ТЕСТОВОЙ ВЕТКОЙ "developer_test":

```
git merge developer_test
```

3)УДАЛИТЬ ТЕСТОВУЮ ВЕТКУ "developer_test":

```
git branch -D developer_test
```

Если у Вас не такой случай, то надо привести к такому случаю, чтобы какая-то 1 ветка была рабочей, обычно это `master`, а на других ветках делают различные фичи  - в вышеописанном алгоритме это ветка `developer_test`. Потом когда все уже работает и оттестена на `developer_test` - ее соединяют с основной - в вышеописанном - это `master`

Answer (score 0):

Если в ветке хотфикс нужный вам файл изменен в одном коммите - вы можете  применить отдельно этот коммит к ветке мастер командой

```
git cherry-pick master
```

выполненной когда вы стоите на нужном коммите.

Так же вы можете для "ненужно изменненого файла" - для него одного сбросить изменения, например так на один коммит назад:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- my-file.txt
```

и таким образом исключить эти неверные изменения из ветки хотфикс